# In Indonesia, is import duty levied on items intended as gifts?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, electronic-items, indonesia, fees-and-charges, import-taxes

My brother teaches English in Jakarta and is getting married in Bali in two weeks. I am going to his wedding. I'm flying into Jakarta and will be there a few days.

As a wedding gift, I bought a new MacBook Pro and am bringing it to my brother. I'd like to avoid paying import fees for this computer.

Obviously I am going to enter the country with the computer and exit without the computer. I understand that if I do not re-export electronic equipment I may have to pay a fee; see http://www.tripadvisor.com/Travel-g294225-c2418/Indonesia:Customs.html.

I understand fees are imposed when selling items, but this is a gift. Do I need to pay this fee, and if not, how can I ensure I don't end up paying any fees when departing the country?

Please note that Indonesia has a reputation for its officials charging money for things they should not charge money for (i.e., corruption).

Comment: How about if you make it appear as if it is your own computer? Ditch the packaging and take it in your carry-on.

Comment: Yep, that's what I plan to do. The thing in worried about is that I won't be bringing it back home with me. So I'll be importing but not exporting...I wonder if they would notice and charge me.

Comment: They won't notice unless your bringing the computer into the country is somehow recorded at entry. I'm not familiar with Indonesian customs, but some countries do ask visitors whether they have any valuables that are not for personal use. But, visitors that bring in a computer for personal use, which for all intents and purposes looks to be for personal use, don't get their possessions recorded on an entry form. So, in short, as long as you don't say a thing, you should be fine.

Comment: I think the general policy on this site is that we don't give people advice on how to break the law.

Comment: It's not breaking the law dude. They are charging me in a corrupt manner. I'm not importing and selling anything; I'm doing nothing illegal.

Comment: @ChadJohnson Perhaps consider rephrasing the question as "In Indonesia, is import duty levied on items intended as gifts for a nonresident soon to depart the country?" or similar. This would make it obvious that you're wondering if your import would be subject to the duty, while the current wording clearly makes some readers think you want to avoid paying duty you legally might owe

Comment: I'm not confident enough to give this as an answer, but if you go to http://www.beacukai.go.id/wwwbcgoid/index.html?page=apps/browse-tarif-dan-lartas.html and enter HS code 847130, it appears to say the tax duty rate on laptop computers is 0.

Comment: @ChadJohnson But you are. Taking an item from your country to another one, as a gift to someone who lives in the second country, is importing a good. What you are planning to do is _exactly_ what import companies are doing, only on a vastly smaller scale. You are "cheating" Indonesia out of the taxes it is imposing on regular companies, and you are "cheating" those companies out of the sale of the MBP. The fact that you are trying to avoid "corruption" (avoiding a supposed wrong by committing a wrong does not make a right, as the saying almost goes.) doesn't make it right.

Comment: "oh, those 10 pallets of computers are gifts to all my friends who're just reimbursing me for the cost of bringing them into the country".

Comment: Coming back to this, I am glad I brought the computer in, claiming it as my own. Otherwise, they would have charged me a 50% tax on the computer. Call me unethical for what I did, but I strongly believe that them charging a 50% tax for the computer would have been very unethical.

Answer (score 3):

### Import Duty Exempted Items (Personal Use)

According to Indonesian Customs, [personal goods of a value ≤ 250`USD` per person (or ≤ 1000`USD` per family) are exempt from import duty](http://www.beacukai.go.id/wwwbcgoid/index.html?page=faq/shall-i-pay-import-duty-for-goods-that-i-bring-into-indonesia.html). Moreover, electronic items that are intended for personal use can be imported without paying duties as long as they are re-exported when leaving the country. Quoting from the linked website:

> #### Shall I pay Import Duty for goods that I bring into Indonesia?
>
> Passengers goods is exempted from Import Duty and other import levies, if the amount less than FOB USD 250 for each person or less than FOB USD 1,000 for each family If the amount is more than aforementioned amount, the passenger shall pay Import Duty and other import levies for the difference. Foreign passengers goods such as camera, video camera, radio cassette, binocular, laptop, or cellular phone, that will be used during stay in Indonesia and will be brought back when leaving for Indonesia also get the exemption.

Since you are planning to leave the laptop in Indonesia as a gift to your sibling, and since the value of the brand new item is > 250`USD`, **you'll have to declare the latop to customs**, and possibly pay import duty on it.

### Calculating Import Duty and Taxes

The import duty on laptops is 0%, according to [Indonesian Customs (search for HS code: 8471302000)](http://www.beacukai.go.id/wwwbcgoid/index.html?page=apps/browse-tarif-dan-lartas.html):

[image: Laptop duty and taxes Indonesia]

This does not mean that importing laptops in Indonesia is free. Indeed, [income tax and VAT are also levied on imports](http://www.dutycalculator.com/country-guides/Import-duty-taxes-when-importing-into-Indonesia/). A rapid simulation with the [Duty Calculator gives the following results](http://www.dutycalculator.com/new-import-duty-and-tax-calculation/saved_calculations/view_details/197885435/), assuming a laptop value of 1500`USD`:

[image: Duty calculator results]

Which gives a total import tax of  5229375.00`IDR` which is approximately 369.57`USD` as of today's exchange rate according to google (1`IDR` = 0.000071`USD`).